# Custom jQuery gradient color picker - making it 'user-friendly'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, color-picker

So, I made [a very simple custom jQuery gradient color picker](http://jsfiddle.net/miskhanception/L8aowq16/), where a user can change certain HTML elements' color to any gradient they want. However, the issue with this is not many people know how to create a gradient. And doing so every time would be a huge hassle. Like, say:

```
#id {
background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
}
```

And with that one, a user would have to type in that every time to achieve a gradient of blue -> red in a left -> right direction. Thus, I attempted to create [a script](http://jsfiddle.net/miskhanception/8fa9yro8/) that simplified it all. However, as you can see, it doesn't really work.

Basically, I created 3 input boxes: One for the gradient motion (e.g., right, left, etc.), one for the beginning gradient color, and one for the ending gradient color. A user would fill in those values, I would grab them all with .val(), then create one final variable which contained this value:

```
'linear-gradient(to gradientMotionVariable, beginningGradientColor, endingGradientColor)'
```

And then, finally, have the div's background property be changed to that variable. I tried searching both Google and SO for this, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sgCp').click(function () {
        var gM = $('#cGp-motion').val();
        var bC = $('#cGp-bC').val();
        var eC = $('#cGp-eC').val();
        var FGC = 'linear-gradient(to ' + gM + ', ' + bC + ', ' + eC + ')';
        $('#cPr').css('background', FGC);
    });
});
```

The problem with your code was that you were passing the css a value that didn't actually use the variable values but passed in the variable names.

**See your**:

`var FGC = 'linear-gradient(to gM, bC, eC)';`

**Compared to my**:

`var FGC = 'linear-gradient(to ' + gM + ', ' + bC + ', ' + eC + ')';`